# Python ftplib: Getting number of files from FTP

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Am new to Python and using FTPLib for some reason.

My aim is, am having a server where files with `.txt` will be stored by different clients very frequently. With `nlst()` function I could get the files present in the FTP server. But it returns all the files. Since the server has hell lot of files the response time is slow.

Is there any way to get the first twenty elements from the FTP using some function and then next twenty? This way I could improve the response time from FTP server considerably.

Regards

Comment: What kind of server are you running?

Comment: When you try to retrieve the listing in parts, the overall time will actually increase. So what's the point? Do you want to provide a feedback to the user about the progress of the listing?

Answer (score 0):

No there's no standard way to retrieve directory listing by parts in FTP protocol.

---

Some FTP servers do support wildcards in the listing commands (`NLST` and alike). So you could get first all file starting with `a`, then with `b`, etc. But you have to test this specifically with your server, as it is a non-standard behavior.